# What type of array do I use if I want to set the size of the array and I want nulls in the empty spots

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-adapter

I want to use a type of array that has a set size (so I need to set the size myself) but I don't want the empty spots in the array to be discarded, I want them to just be null.
Basically I have an Adapter that fills a ListView with pictures and text. I get the text and picture links using two String arrays (**fragment**):

```
String[] itemNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.catItems);
String[] itemLinks =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.catLinks);

mMenuItems = findViewById(R.id.menuItems);
mMenuItems.setAdapter(new MenuCatAdapter(this, itemLinks, itemNames));
```

I want to set the length of the itemLinks array to be the same as the itemNames array. In the MenuAdapter I use the following code in the getView() method to set the text and the images for the ListView (**fragment**):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View customView = convertView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(customView == null) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
        customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_cat_list_item, parent, false);

        holder.itemImage = customView.findViewById(R.id.navCatImageView);
        holder.itemName = customView.findViewById(R.id.navCatTextView);

        customView.setTag(holder);
    }  else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) customView.getTag();
    }

    // Set the image
    if(mImageLinks[position] == null) { //What to do if the link is non-existent
        Glide   .with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.sidebar_sandwich)
                .into(holder.itemImage);
    } else {
        Glide   .with(mActivity.getApplicationContext())
                .load(mImageLinks[position])
                .into(holder.itemImage);
    }
    holder.itemImage.setContentDescription(mItemNames[position]);
    // Set the text
    holder.itemName.setText(mItemNames[position]);

    return customView;
}
```

I want to make sure that even if I don't have a link for the image (so the link is null), I still get a placeholder image (or no image), instead of getting an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use a type of array that has a set size (so I need to set the size myself) but I don't want the empty spots in the array to be discarded, I want them to just be null.

Every Java array has a fixed length which must be provided at declaration time. Further, if it is an array of a reference type, then the default value **is** `null`. So,

```
String[] arr = new String[1];
```

creates an array with enough room to store a single `String`. And the default value is a `null`, for that reason

```
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

Outputs

```
null
```

Comment: Yes but, If I try to set a resource for the array that default size is overridden, so that solution cannot work.

Comment: Don't set a resource for the array. Or rather, set the resource for a temporary array and then **copy** the values programmatically to the other one.

Comment: Thanks for that. The way I did it was the following:                   `String[] itemLinks = new String[itemNames.length];
            String[] temp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.catImages);
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, itemLinks, 0, temp.length);`